# How to get the latest 5 company data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in mysql database.

a) company

```
cid    company_name  
===================
1      AstraZeneca
2      Emirates
3      Development Bank of Singapore
4      Royal Copenhagen
5      xxx  
6      xxx
```

2) history

```
hid   user_id   view_id  is_save  mark_as  view date
==============================================================
1     2         2        0        3        2016-08-25 22:06:12
2     3         3        1        3        2016-08-25 22:07:12
3     3         3        0        1        2016-08-25 22:08:12
4     3         2        0        1        2016-08-25 22:09:12
5     2         4        0        1        2016-08-25 22:10:12
6     4         5        0        1        2016-08-25 22:11:12
7     4         6        0        1        2016-08-25 22:12:12
```

This `view_id` is containing `cid` value.

Now, always I want to show latest 5 `company_name` from `company` table as **ascending order** based on `history` table `view_id`.

For that purpose I am doing following query. But `company_name` is not showing either `ASC` or `DESC` order

**Here is the query :**

```
$getViewID3 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT view_id, hid, is_save FROM history WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND mark_as = 3 GROUP BY view_id ORDER BY view_date DESC LIMIT 5 ");  

if(mysqli_num_rows($getViewID3) > 0 ) { 

   while( $fetchViewId3 = mysqli_fetch_array($getViewID3) ) {
   $viewid3 = (int) $fetchViewId3['view_id'];
   $hid3 = (int) $fetchViewId3['hid'];
   $is_save3 = (int) $fetchViewId3['is_save'];

   $getCompany = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE cid = '$viewid3' ORDER BY company_name DESC");

   if(mysqli_num_rows($getCompany) > 0 ) {

      while ($fetchCompany2  = mysqli_fetch_array($getCompany)) {
         $cName = htmlspecialchars($fetchCompany2['company_name']);
         $url_link = "{$url}company.php?cid=$viewid";

         if($is_save3 == 1) {
            $checked = 'checked = "checked"';
         } else {
            $checked = '';
         }

         echo "<li><a onClick='window.document.location=\"$url_link\"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;$cName </a> <input type='checkbox' class='data_save' $checked data-hid='$hid' data-saveid='$viewid3' name='save_history'></li>";
      }   
   }
}
```

For example : Result is showing : A, E, D, R, L letter order. 
It's should be show : A, D, E, L, R letter Order from `company_name` column.

Comment: Can you put some distinguishing company names in your sample data and include your expected output ?

Comment: @1000111 I am updating...\

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: @Strawberry, can you show me how the join query should look like because I have already did but not worked for me !

Comment: 50% done. Expected output is worth many words.

Comment: View_id is not unique, so what happens in the event of a tie?

Comment: I want to get latest 5 view_id. So If I get latest 5 view_id based on view_date or whatever method then I can get company_name column data. This view_id is company table cid value.

Comment: why @Strawberry ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand:

```
SELECT 
C.company_name
FROM company C 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    view_id,
    MAX(view_date) max_view_date
    FROM history 
    WHERE is_save IN (0,1) AND mark_as = 3
    GROUP BY view_id
    ORDER BY max_view_date DESC 
    LIMIT 5
) AS t
ON C.cid = t.view_id
ORDER BY C.company_name ASC;
```

**Note:**

Since you want latest 5 companies the following query will put the last `view_date` beside the `view_id`.

Now if you sort these rows based on **descending** order of `max_view_date` and later limit the result to `5` then you will get at most five `view_id`s from the inner query.

Later a simple `INNER JOIN` between this result set and your company table will finish the job.

Sorry, sorting the final result in ascending order of company name will finish the job.

**EDIT:**

In order to get all the columns from `history` table and `company_name` column from `company` table:

```
SELECT 
C.company_name,
t.*
FROM company C 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    history.*
    FROM history
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        view_id,
        MAX(view_date) max_view_date
        FROM history 
        WHERE is_save IN (0,1) AND mark_as = 3
        GROUP BY view_id
        ORDER BY max_view_date DESC 
        LIMIT 5
    ) AS latestHistory
    ON history.view_id = latestHistory.view_id AND history.view_date = latestHistory.max_view_date
) AS t
ON C.cid = t.view_id
ORDER BY C.company_name ASC;
```

Comment: That's why I asked for the expected output. By the way, which columns do you want in your expected output list?

Comment: Output will be company_name value but condition is :  which `is_save` = 1 or 0 and mark_as = 3. Sorry, for my misunderstanding.

Comment: I've added those two conditions in the where clause. please check now.

Comment: sure. I am checking it

Comment: Error :  Undefined index: is_save in

Comment: I will do condition using is_save value in while loop. So I need the is_save value from the query result.

Comment: Look at the answer under edit section. You will get all the columns from `history` table and company name column from company table. First ensure that the query alone is giving you expected output. Later integrate it in your code.

Comment: i have a simple issue. Now the data is coming from 2 tables. a) company and b) history. Now If I want to get data from `contact_details` table then how the query look like ?

Comment: You need to define the relationship among these three tables first. The rest of the task will be based on that. @shibbirahmed

Comment: I did it. Thanks.

Comment: Question : stackoverflow.com/questions/39200035/how-can-i-show-unique-data-from-php-while-loop-results-not-by-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment65740466_39200035